# Unpredictable behavior in Java Thread Pool while capturing response for multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to add 10 records to different server with the help of thread pool and waiting for response to get the information added on server side, but when I execute the code at my end I am getting same response for few threads, but data stored at server end are unique values per record.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
List<Future<Employee>> listOfEmployee = new ArrayList<Future<Employee>>();
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    listOfEmployee.add(threadPool.submit(new Callable<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public Employee call() 
        {
            return employee.add();
        }
    }));
}
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
for(Future<Employee> future : listOfEmployee)
{
     employeeList.add(future.get());
}
```

what can be the root cause for the problem?

Comment: It looks like you can completely remove the threads from this problem and does it work then? What does employee.add do? What is employee?

Comment: yes when we remove the threads it works completely fine, and our employee.add() auto generated all the attributes of employee and add to the list present in different server and send a response from server of Employee type.

Comment: You are using thread-unsafe data structures and operations.

Comment: You'll need to include the employee.add method to get any help then, also you need to state some explicit quantity that is "incorrect" eg. On the server it is "A" bet the values in employeeList all contain "B".

Comment: Output we received :
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 9
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 8
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 6
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 1
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 9
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 3
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 0
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 6
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 6
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 6

Here we can see that there is two Id’s 6 and 9 are 

repeated.

Comment: But when we fetch the list of Employees directly from CompanyId we will receive something like this(which is our expectation from thread also to receive in response),

CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 0
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 1
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 2
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 3
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 4
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 5
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 6
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 7
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 8
CompanyId : 0 EmployeeId : 9

Comment: @user207421 can you explain what is thread- unsafe data structures and how would I make it run successfully?